# EGit Multiple Branches Issue

Tags: eclipse, spring-boot, github, git-branch, egit

I'm fairly new to using EGit and Github, and want to resolve something. A few days ago I was trying to revert to a previous commit of my Java Spring Boot App because I was unhappy with my project edits I'd made that day. At this time I had one "master" branch with a bunch of different commits. To revert to a previous commit, I was either incorrectly suggested or I incorrectly tried to "checkout" this commit, and mistakenly created a new branch while doing so. So now I have two branches, where the latest one has all the updated code. Is there any way to merge the 2 branches, keeping all the code and everything the same? I just want there to be 1 master branch so that I and my co-developers can see all the commits in chronological order with ease, and not be confused by the fact that there's 2 branches. Thanks and sorry for my inexperience with this!

Answer (score 0):

Two scenarios here

**1. You want master branch but you dont want recent commit. you want to replace it with previous**

Solution

A. perform pull operation on your project now you have all the latest file

B. select file which you want to replace with previous commit.right click on file and select replace with -->commit-->choose commit you want to replace from list

C.perform commit and push

D. repeat same procedure for each file.

**2.You want only master branch with latest Commit and want to delete another branch**

Solution.

A. perform pull operation on your project now you have all the latest file

B.Go to repository window-->branches-->local branch-->select branch you want to delete and push the changes